# Replace the editable Select2Cell's value with the text (linked to value) in the Backgrid table which is already rendered from the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, backgrid

**What is already implemented:**
We have a page where the Backgrid table is rendered from `table1` in database (which is working fine) and most of the cells in the Backgrid are editable. The cells are left editable so that the existing details can be displayed in the grid and at the same time could be edited if required. Further new rows could be added by double-clicking on one of the cells in the empty row.

**What needs to be achieved:**
There is a column (`clientid`) which currently displays only the ID numbers, but we need the cell to display the `client-name` based on the existing ID in that cell. These `[clientid,  client-name]` comes from `table2` in the database. Since the cell is also editable, we want the user to be able to select the appropriate client using `Backgrid.Extension.Select2Cell`.

If I refer to this example: http://backgridjs.com/ref/cell.html

```
{
    name: "gender",
    label: "Gender",
    cell: Backgrid.SelectCell.extend({
      // It's possible to render an option group or use a
      // function to provide option values too.
      optionValues: [["Male", "m"], ["Female", "f"]]
    })
```

The `Gender (SelectCell)` will display options to select based on the optionValues defined. Similarly, we'll need the select options to be listed as drop-down (pulled from `table2` in the database as `[clientid,  client-name]`) and at the same time, the content of the cell (from `table1`) should display the text not the ID...so, `Male` not `m` (`m` referring to above example).

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see the problem here...

```
{
  name: "client_id",
  label: "Client",
  cell: Backgrid.SelectCell.extend({
    optionValues: [["Client1", "client1_id"], ["Client2", "client2_id"], ...]
  })
}
```

should work as needed. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the issue is I'm not able to have the `Client1` name displayed (pulled from `table2`) if the cell has value `client1_id` (which comes from `table1`. Note: I do not have the name `Client1` in `table1`).